# Steam losing connection (What firewall rules need to be set?)

Tags: steam, windows-10

I have Steam installed on two Windows 10 machines. They both periodically lose connection:

[image]

Restarting the client restores connection immediately.

What I've tried:

- Updating the Steam client (there are no Steam client updates available).
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the client (does not help).
- Manually changing my DNS settings to OpenDNS or Google DNS (does not help).

Completely disabling the Windows Firewall appeared to resolve the errors, but this is not a permanent solution.

What firewall rules need to be set for Steam?

Comment: Is steam on the List of allowed applications by the firewall?

Comment: @TimmyJim Steam apps are allowed and all inbound rules are enabled and allowed.

Comment: Since you're already connected and losing the connection, and restarting the client allows you to connect, it doesnt sound like a firewall issue. Your firewall seems happy to allow Steam to connect to this network. To totally rule out that as a culprit, next time this happens, completely disable your firewall and see if Steam connects automatically. If not, then it's definitely not a firewall issue.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't automatically connect. It's very odd though that connection is not lost after several hours when the firewall is off, and dies soon after restoring the firewall.

Comment: @Mooseman Firewalls tend to close ports that are "unused" after a while. I'd assume the game or Steam itself implements heartbeating to avoid that issue, but maybe not. I wonder how frequently it tries to reconnect after a disconnect .... maybe it's a long timeout?

Comment: @DanBron Do you know the ports? I can setup Wireshark.

Comment: No, sorry, but `netstat` might be able to tell you.

Comment: Resource Monitor may also help

Answer (score 1):

> **Required Ports for Steam**
>
> Which ports do I need to open on my router or firewall for Steam? To
>   log into Steam and download content: HTTP (TCP port 80) and HTTPS
>   (443) UDP 27015 through 27030 TCP 27015 through 27030
>
> **Steam Client**
>
> UDP 27000 to 27015 inclusive (Game client traffic) UDP 27015 to 27030
>   inclusive (Typically Matchmaking and HLTV) UDP 27031 and 27036
>   (incoming, for In-Home Streaming) TCP 27036 and 27037 (incoming, for
>   In-Home Streaming) UDP 4380
>
> **Dedicated or Listen Servers**
>
> TCP 27015 (SRCDS Rcon port)
>
> **Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat**
>
> UDP 3478 (Outbound) UDP 4379 (Outbound) UDP 4380 (Outbound)
>
> **Note:**
>
> Many university networks and proxies block required ports for Steam
>   operation - please consult your network administrator to ensure the
>   required ports are open if you are using a university network or a
>   proxy. Ports required for Steam can not be re-mapped to HTTP or
>   reconfigured to a custom port range.
>
> **Advanced**
>
> For generic Steam HTTP/HTTPS requests, your proxy should allow the
>   following domains: steampowered.com steamcommunity.com steamgames.com
>   steamusercontent.com steamcontent.com steamstatic.com akamaihd.net

Info was found [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711)